# Tinkerpop-3 Gremlin Not Found For Groovy-Project In IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy, gremlin, graph-databases, tinkerpop3

Why can IntelliJ IDEA not resolve Gremlin for its [`SimpleExample`](https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki/Using-Gremlin-through-Groovy#groovy-classes-with-gremlin)?
I need to make a program that doesn't require intervention / manual steps, so I can't use the gremlin/groovy-shell at time of graph-database demonstration.
How can you make a simple Gremlin-Groovy project?

`Cannot resolve symbol 'Gremlin'`

## Reproduction

### Steps

1. Select-Click a new project in IntelliJ IDEA
2. Fill-in fields and confirm for Gremlin-Project

   1. Language: Groovy
   2. Build System: IntelliJ
   3. JDK: corretto-11
   4. Groovy SDK: 4.0.2 enter image description here
      [image]
3. Navigate-open `Project Structure` (IntelliJ IDEA)
4. [Add libraries](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#gremlin-groovy) to `Project Settings > Libraries` or `Platform Settings > Global Libraries`

   1. `compile group: 'org.apache.tinkerpop', name: 'gremlin-core', version: '3.6.3'`
   2. `compile group: 'org.apache.tinkerpop', name: 'gremlin-driver', version: '3.6.3'`
   3. If I don't import these directly, then it will suggest older TinkerPop-2 which we don't plan to evaluate

      1. `import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.Graph`
      2. `import com.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.Gremlin`
5. Copy-paste latest found [`Groovy Classes with Gremlin`](https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki/Using-Gremlin-through-Groovy#groovy-classes-with-gremlin) found

   1. I couldn't find anything newer
6. Results:

   1. Expected: Import for `Gremlin` would be found: automatically or recommending
   2. Actually: No Gremlin found for IntelliJ IDEA to import for Groovy
      `Cannot resolve symbol 'Gremlin'`

### Layout

```
│   SimpleProject.iml
│
├───.idea
│   │   .gitignore
│   │   misc.xml
│   │   modules.xml
│   │   vcs.xml
│   │
│   └───libraries
│           apache_tinkerpop_gremlin_core.xml
│           apache_tinkerpop_gremlin_driver.xml
│           groovy_4_0_2.xml
│
├───lib
│
└───src
        SimpleExample.groovy
```

### Code

#### `SimpleProject.groovy`

```java
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Graph

class SimpleExample {
  static {
    Gremlin.load()
  }
  public List exampleMethod() {
    Graph g = TinkerGraphFactory.createTinkerGraph()
    def results = []
    g.v(1).out('knows').fill(results)
    return results
  }
}
```

#### `SimpleProject.iml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
  <component name="NewModuleRootManager" inherit-compiler-output="true">
    <exclude-output />
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src" isTestSource="false" />
    </content>
    <orderEntry type="jdk" jdkName="corretto-11" jdkType="JavaSDK" />
    <orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="groovy-4.0.2" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy" level="application" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.core" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver" level="project" />
  </component>
</module>
misc.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="ProjectRootManager" version="2" languageLevel="JDK_11" default="true" project-jdk-name="corretto-11" project-jdk-type="JavaSDK">
    <output url="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/out" />
  </component>
</project>
```

Comment: How are the libraries configured? apache_tinkerpop_gremlin_core.xml
apache_tinkerpop_gremlin_driver.xml. What jars are referenced? Share a sample project on GitHub.

Comment: that `SimpleExample` is from a wiki page (and repository) that has long been deprecated (and is clearly labelled as such). it won't work with the latest version of TinkerPop despite there being similar APIs.

Comment: @stephenmallette I know its long since been deprecated, but I can't find anything newer in time to use. Is there any more recent example of a Gremlin-Groovy-Class?

Comment: @CrazyCoder Here's the [Sample-Project](https://github.com/ZachMurray/SimpleExample)!

Comment: As mentioned above, your example is for an older library version. Find and use some more recent samples.

Comment: @CrazyCoder that's a part of the problem, I cannot find a newer version of the example.

Comment: A part of this post was an SOS to find a newer example to update this trial with.